# ETH Hackathon prerequisites

Tags: solidity

What are the prerequisites to take part in an ethereum hackathon?
I am from europe and there's the ETHBerlin in september. Is it possible to take part even if you're a beginner?

To me it seems like it's a great opportunity to learn from pros.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to take part even if you're a beginner?

It depends on the rules of this particular hackathon.

But I can say that participating in hackathons in my country doesn't mean you have to be proficient in Ethereum development or blockchain in general. Usually there are many categories of people who team up and work on a project doing different roles. So, don't be afraid, you can always join some team and be useful in one way or another. But if this is solo-hackathon, it might be good to learn something before participating. To start learning how to develop dapps you can start with cryptozombies, truffle pet shop, ethernaut, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Last weekend I attended the Eth Buenos Aires event which is part of the same group of events run by Eth Global. It was a great experience and definitely recommend people to get involved in these events. In the hackathon there was a mixture of people from beginner to advanced levels so if you are interested you should sign up. Still a few months until September anyway to get some more practice.